# Antlr: "no viable alternative at input 'start 001 vs 003'"

Tags: antlr

I am doing some work with Antlr and Python and have come across this error message "line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'start 001 vs 003'" but have no idea what to do with it or how to fix it.

```
start: expr | <EOF>;

expr
        : 'start' duration=DURATION 'fight' player_1=FILE 'vs' player_2=FILE #durationfightExpr
        ;

FILE : ('A'..'Z'|'a'..'z'|'0'..'9'|':'|'\\'|'/'|' '|'-'|'_'|'.')+ ;
DURATION : ('0' .. '9') + ('.' ('0' .. '9') +)?;
WS : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

For the input `start 001 vs 003`, the lexer creates just 1 `FILE` token. You'll probably want to exclude the white space char from `FILE`:

```
FILE : ('A'..'Z'|'a'..'z'|'0'..'9'|':'|'\\'|'/'|'-'|'_'|'.')+ ;
```

But then you run into the problem that the following tokens are created:

```
'start'              `start`
FILE                 `001`
'vs'                 `vs`
FILE                 `003`
```

I.e. both `001` and `003` are `FILE` tokens. Because `FILE` can match this input too, and because it is placed *before* `DURATION`, int/double kind of input will always become a `FILE`. But if you these rules:

```
DURATION : ('0' .. '9') + ('.' ('0' .. '9') +)?;
FILE : ('A'..'Z'|'a'..'z'|'0'..'9'|':'|'\\'|'/'|'-'|'_'|'.')+ ;
```

then input like `001` will never become a `FILE` token (perhaps that's OK for you, I don't know). Note that these rules can be written more succinctly like this:

```
DURATION : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;
FILE : [A-Za-z0-9:\\/\-_.]+;
```